# getting all content of html

Tags: python, html

I have problem when I want to display HTML using python this the result :

[image]

And this is the original from the website and I want to display mine (using python) as the original with "My Characters" :

[image]

This is the code source :

```
result2 = scraper.get("https://www.dofus-touch.com/en/mmorpg/community/directories/character-pages/2225800401-kaidou",headers=heads)
    hugo = result2.content
    baba = BeautifulSoup(hugo, "html.parser")
    print(baba)
```

Comment: the `character` tab probably is generated by javascript

Comment: @LinhNguyen And what is the solution?

Comment: i'm not familiar with BeautifulSoup but you can look up how to crawl javascript generated content in html with your scraper

Comment: @LinhNguyen But "My characters" is div not javascript I've just saw it

Comment: yes that what i mean by `generated by javascript`, some html content like div,... can be generated by javascript. IF you want to check if it's generated by javascript, download the html page with ctrl+s on that page, open up downloaded html file to check if that div is in the html

Comment: @LinhNguyen Yes, I found it :/ and it's downloadable

Comment: @LinhNguyen So this is not javascript

Comment: Saving the HTML file with ctrl+s downlods the file after Javascript has already run. So it may still be generated by javascript.

Comment: @rdas So what is the solution for this problem ?

Comment: Use something like selenium or chrome headless

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are logged in into your account so you can see the list of characters you have.

Your scraper on the other hand does not have such information about your account so he is treated as guest user with no characters list rendered.

To solve this problem you need to send the request with the right headers/cookies to tell the server that it's you.

The short solution here would be to track the network requests when you open this page and copy this specific request as curl

[image]

Now to see the results visually, let's use postman

First I will make the request as you usually did it with the url https://www.dofus-touch.com/en/mmorpg/community/directories/character-pages/2225800401-kaidou

[image]

As you can see, I'm not logged in yet because I requested the page with no headers.
Now let's try again using the curl we copied, by selecting import and pasting the curl text

[image]

As you can see, I'm logged in as newguy5 which is my username I just created an account with, unfortunately I don't have any characters in my account but I assume you do have.

Now we want to turn this into code, we can use the automatic code conversion provided by postman, that will generate

```
import requests

url = "https://www.dofus-touch.com/en/mmorpg/community/directories/character-pages/2225800401-kaidou"

payload = {}
headers = {
  'authority': 'www.dofus-touch.com',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
  'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ar;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
  'cookie': 'your_own_cookie_here',
  'Cookie': 'your_own_cookie_here'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

I removed my cookies values but yours will be there when the code is generated.

There are more advanced approaches, which is writing a script to automatically log in and get those cookies but I'm not sure if you need that in your usecase so you can start with what I explained above then if build on it as you go.

Comment: Always "My characters" hide

Comment: It's work only when I copy cookies from the website to header , if you know how to get cookies using python I think it's good idea